# getting the MasterViewController from the DetailViewController in a UISplitViewController app

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a standard SplitViewController app in Swift in Xcode 6.1.1.  It would be very convenient for my DetailViewController have a pointer to my MasterViewController.  (I don't need to send notifications, but I need to pull the current statemachine from my MVC)

My thought was that I would use my DetailViewController viewDidLoad method to grab the MasterViewController from the SplitViewController.

In my DetailViewController:viewDidLoad I have

```
(snip)

    let tVC = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UIViewController
    let tNav = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController
    let tMVC = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? MasterViewController
```

When I inspect these, my tVC and tNav variables were successfully set, but my tMVC was nil.  I thought that the splitViewController.viewController[0] would give me my MasterViewController directly, but I'm getting a UINavigationController instead.

Am I wrong/is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
let tNav = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController
if let tMVC = tNav?.topViewController as? MasterViewController {
        masterViewController = tMVC
        stateMachine = tMVC.stateMachine
    }
```

Comment: This cast always fails for me. I'm also calling it from viewDidLoad in my DetailViewController. I wonder if something has changed in 6.3.