# ISplitViewController: Can DetailViewController load data from MasterVIewController without segueing back?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

Amateur here. I have created an iOS Swift app using UISplitViewController. It works well so far. 
I would like to be able to load data stored in the MasterViewController whilst viewing the DetailViewController view, without segueing back to the MasterViewContoler view and selecting an item in the UITableView presented there. Phew, what a mouthful, I hope that makes sense. Is this possible? I am not sure how to proceed. These images may explain better:

[Detail View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRidc.png)

[Master View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVyzJ.png)

I have read these questions: [getting the MasterViewController from the DetailViewController in a UISplitViewController app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151415/getting-the-masterviewcontroller-from-the-detailviewcontroller-in-a-uisplitviewc) and [SplitView - reload data in master tableView based on detail changed in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555223/splitview-reload-data-in-master-tableview-based-on-detail-changed-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1) but they are not quite what I am looking for.

This is my DetailViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var compareToButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func compareToButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //do something here?
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var pathologyImageViewOne: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pathologyImageViewTwo: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailUsedLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailReferenceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailPhotoOneCaptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailPhotoTwoCaptionLabel: UILabel!

    var caseIDOne = 0
    var caseIDTwo = 0
    var compareToButtonString = "Hello"


    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = detailItem {
            if let detailDescriptionLabel = detailDescriptionLabel,
                let compareToButton = compareToButton,
                let detailUsedLabel = detailUsedLabel,
                let pathologyImageViewOne = pathologyImageViewOne,
                let pathologyImageViewTwo = pathologyImageViewTwo,
                let detailReferenceLabel = detailReferenceLabel,
                let detailPhotoOneCaptionLabel = detailPhotoOneCaptionLabel,
                let detailPhotoTwoCaptionLabel = detailPhotoTwoCaptionLabel {

                title = detail.name
                caseIDOne = detail.caseIDOne
                caseIDTwo = detail.caseIDTwo!

                detailDescriptionLabel.text = detail.description
                compareToButtonString = detail.compareTo!

                UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                    compareToButton.setTitle("\(compareToButtonString)", for: .normal)
                }

                detailUsedLabel.text = detail.used
                detailReferenceLabel.text = detail.reference

                pathologyImageViewOne.image = UIImage(named: detail.photoOne)
                pathologyImageViewOne.layer.cornerRadius = 4
                pathologyImageViewOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                pathologyImageViewOne.clipsToBounds = true

                pathologyImageViewTwo.image = UIImage(named: detail.photoTwo!)
                pathologyImageViewTwo.layer.cornerRadius = 4
                pathologyImageViewTwo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                pathologyImageViewTwo.clipsToBounds = true

                // The image in the foreground
                let frontImage = UIImage(named: "tap-icon")
                // Create the view holding the image
                let frontImageViewOne = UIImageView(image: frontImage)
                // The size and position of the front image
                frontImageViewOne.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 34, height: 42)
                // turn off AutoresingMask
                frontImageViewOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                // change alpha
                frontImageViewOne.alpha = 0.8

                // Create the view holding the image again
                let frontImageViewTwo = UIImageView(image: frontImage)
                // The size and position of the front image again
                frontImageViewTwo.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 34, height: 42)
                // turn off AutoresingMask again
                frontImageViewTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                // change alpha again
                frontImageViewTwo.alpha = 0.8



                //MARK: Image One
                // Add the front image on top of the background
                pathologyImageViewOne.addSubview(frontImageViewOne)

                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    //place the tap icon at the bottom right of parent
                    frontImageViewOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pathologyImageViewOne.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
                    frontImageViewOne.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pathologyImageViewOne.rightAnchor, constant: -24)
                    ])


                let tapGestureRecognizerOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizerOne:)))
                pathologyImageViewOne.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                pathologyImageViewOne.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerOne)

                //MARK: Image two
                // Add the front image on top of the background
                pathologyImageViewTwo.addSubview(frontImageViewTwo)

                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    //place the tap icon at the bottom right of parent
                    frontImageViewTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pathologyImageViewTwo.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
                    frontImageViewTwo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pathologyImageViewTwo.rightAnchor, constant: -24)
                    ])


                let tapGestureRecognizerTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizerTwo:)))
                pathologyImageViewTwo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                pathologyImageViewTwo.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerTwo)

                detailPhotoOneCaptionLabel.text = detail.photoOneCaption

                detailPhotoTwoCaptionLabel.text = detail.photoTwoCaption

            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        configureView()

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.layoutMargins  = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    }

    var detailItem: Descriptor? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
           configureView()
        }
    }


    func showWebsite(_ whichCase: Int) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://digitalpathology.uct.ac.za/case_detail.php?case_id=\(whichCase)") {
            let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
            config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
            present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }



    @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizerOne: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {

       showWebsite(caseIDOne)
       print("Image tapped")
       print("CaseOne ID = \(caseIDOne)")
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizerTwo: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {

        showWebsite(caseIDTwo)
        print("Image tapped")
        print("CaseTwo ID = \(caseIDTwo)")
    }


}
```

My edited (for brevity) MasterViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchFooter: SearchFooter!

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil

    var descriptors = [Descriptor]()

    var filteredDescriptors = [Descriptor]()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    fileprivate var collapseDetailViewController = true

    // MARK: - view setup
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup the Search Controller
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Descriptors"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

        definesPresentationContext = true

        //delagate and data source commented out, connected in storyboard
        //tableView.delegate = self
        //tableView.dataSource = self

        // The data
        descriptors = [
            Descriptor(name:"Friable", description:"Easily crumbled. Said of tissue that readily tears, fragments, or bleeds when gently palpated or manipulated.", photoOne: "Friable", photoOneCaption:"Subacute bacterial edocarditis",  used:"Used in relation to – heart valve vegetations, brittle carcinomatous tissue esp. of cervix.", reference: "Ref: DMD", caseIDOne:769),           
            Descriptor(name:"Hypertrophic / Hypertrophied", description:"An enlarged, overgrown or bulky organ or part, on account of an increase in the size of its cells (compare ‘hyperplastic’).", compareTo: "Hyperplastic", photoOne: "Hypertrophic1", photoOneCaption:"The heart in hypertension", photoTwo: "Hypertrophic2", photoTwoCaption:"The heart in hypertension", used:"Used in relation to – over-exercised muscles or muscular organs such as heart, bladder, stomach.", reference: "Ref: FPMD", caseIDOne:833, caseIDTwo:833),
            Descriptor(name:"Hyperplastic", description:"An enlarged or expanded organ or part, on account of an increase in the formation and number of normal cells (compare ‘hypertrophy’). Hyperplastic expansion may be uniform or nodular.",  compareTo: "Hypertrophy", photoOne: "Hyperplastic", photoOneCaption:"Hyperplastic gastropathy in Zollinger-Ellison syndrome", used:"Used in relation to - a benign expansion of the prostate, an endo- or epithelium, lymph node, gums or endocrine glands, usually reflecting hyper-stimulation of some cause.", reference: "Ref: MKEDMNAH", caseIDOne:555),]

        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
           detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
        //splitViewController?.delegate = self as? UISplitViewControllerDelegate
        splitViewController?.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if splitViewController!.isCollapsed {
            if let selectionIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
            }
         }



        //lets sort the array of objects so A comes before Z
        descriptors.sort { $0.name.compare($1.name) == .orderedAscending }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }


    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let descriptor: Descriptor
                if isFiltering() {
                    descriptor = filteredDescriptors[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    descriptor = descriptors[indexPath.row]
                }
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = descriptor

                collapseDetailViewController = false

                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

                let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
                backItem.title = "Pathology A-Z"
                navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering() {
            searchFooter.setIsFilteringToShow(filteredItemCount: filteredDescriptors.count, of: descriptors.count)
            return filteredDescriptors.count
        }
        searchFooter.setNotFiltering()
        return descriptors.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let descriptor: Descriptor
        if isFiltering() {
            descriptor = filteredDescriptors[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            descriptor = descriptors[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.textLabel!.text = descriptor.name
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = descriptor.description
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return false
    }

extension MasterViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return collapseDetailViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried your solution yet but I will get back to you as soon as I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepare a method for default case. Say, declare `detailDefaultItem` in your `DetailViewController` and assign to `detailItem` in `viewDidLoad` before `configureView()` (just remove it, cuz it will already call in `didSet` of `detailItem`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var detailDefaultItem = Descriptor()
    // set/configure needed default values in `Descriptor` class or here below
    // detailDefaultItem.property = someValue
    // ...
    detailItem = detailDefaultItem
    // configureView()
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Agisight, this worked (I'm sorry about the long delay)